# MongoDB match aggregation where value equals multiple search items

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm writing a match to try and return documents that have any of the values in the array `[1, 2, 8]` match to `ptCode`. If none of the numbers matches then don't return anything. Below what I have written only returns the value of 1 but also still returns something if none of the numbers match.

```
match = {'$and': [{'underlying': underlying},
                  {'ptCode': {'$in': [1, 2, 8]}}]}
```

In SQL I would write:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE underlying = 'something'
AND ptCode IN (1, 2, 8)
```

Is there an issue with the syntax? How do I fix it to match the SQL I have written above.

Comment: I would put the second underlying in apostrophe. Let me know if it works, I have some other ideas too, if that's not enough.

Comment: @CeliusStingher Sorry I should have clarified. The second underlying is a variable parsed in as a parameter.

Comment: Are you running this from python or mongo?

Comment: @CeliusStingher This is running from python that gets passed into a pipeline aggregate function.

Comment: @UsmanKhan : Please provide sample docs, Did you check on underlying being sent properly ? also make sure ptCode in DB is numbers, You don't need to do $and,  (your code should work, but anyway) , try this :::> db.getCollection('yourCollection').aggregate([{$match : {'underlying': 'something','ptCode': {'$in': [1, 2, 8]}}}])